# Microsoft Access Database and Unicode Charset

Tags: microsoft-access

Im trying to edit the database of a program to make it output unicode or utf8 characters. As of now the characters appear as question marks. The database tables contains strings like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
```

How do I edit this string to make it display unicode when the program is run?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you working in the table, a form, a query, a report or VBA? Does "make it output" mean to export the data or display on the screen?

Comment: This is a table in the database which is responsible for outputting a tring in the program.

Comment: The table stores the items as input. So, it's the program which needs to be made to see it in Unicode. This may have more to do with environmental variables or ODBC settings than with the Access table itself. What program is reading the table?

Comment: a program called Trivia Master. Its used for trivia in a Paltalk chatroom.